# Redirect to another page after clicking submit

Tags: html, forms

I have this form, but when i click submit it takes me to `contactform/contact.php`. 
I still need the `action="contactform/contact.php"` as it contains the information.

I need to redirect it to go to another link example `google.com` once they click submit. I know there is a way but i cant remember it and it goes on the line of the submit which i believe was in JavaScript.

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" method="post" action="contactform/contact.php">
  <div class="form-option" id="main-font">Name:</div>
  <div><input class="required inpt" type="text" name="name" value="" /></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="form-option" id="main-font">Email:</div>
  <div><input class="required inpt" type="text" name="email" value="" /></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="form-option" id="main-font">Phone:</div>
  <div><input class="required inpt" type="text" name="phone" value="" /></div> 
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <label id="load"></label><input name="submit" type="image" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
  </div>           
</form>
```

In the contact.php is the code for the required fields if they are missing or not. If the fields are filled and click submit it takes you to contact.php and it gives you an "OK"

I need to change the "ok" in this take me to example.com

```
 if($mail)
    {
echo 'OK';
   if($autorespond =="yes")
 {
    include_once("autoresponde.php");
   }
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

 }
```

Comment: Why do you need to redirect again? You can check if the form is submitted on the target page and later do a header-call to redirect to the page you want to redirect to. Or am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what you need? You want to redirect the request after a user has filled out the form, or you need to redirect the output to another site?

Comment: In the contact.php is the code for the required fields if they are missing or not. If the fields are filled and click submit it takes you to contact.php and it gives you an "OK"

I need to change the "ok" in this take me to example.com

if($mail)
 {
echo 'OK';
if($autorespond =="yes")
{
 include_once("autoresponde.php");
}
 }

 }
 else
 {
 echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
 }

}

Answer (score 1):

JS wouldn't help much. By the time it could trigger, the user's already leaving the page to hit your form handler script, meaning that the form page itself and any code on it is being shut down.

You should just redirect in your form handler

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   ... handle form...
}

if ($form_processed_successfully) {
   header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: When i hit submit it shows "ok". on this form i would ilke to change the echo 'ok' and make it go to example.com without having to click on a link, so in other words just redirect. Can you help?

     if($mail)
       {
     echo 'OK';
       if($autorespond =="yes")
         {

Comment: which is exactly what the above code would do. the form submits to that script, the data's processed, and then the user gets redirected.

Comment: would i put this on the contact.php form? sorry im pretty new to PHP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code should help. This jQuery code will listen to your submit request and would wait for 2 seconds before redirecting user.

```
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Remove this line if you want to submit the form data as well.
    var i = 0;
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    i++; // Just making sure that browser get enough time to submit data to server.
    },1000);

    if(i==2) { 
    window.location = "http://www.google.com" 
    clearInterval(x);
    }


});
```